# I'm trying to sort an array at least at greatest. Now I've got something just like this:

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
//Creating the array
int[] n = {2, 9, 56, 73, 32, 8, 23, 21, 12, 53, 9, 0, 1};

//Creating the sorting algoritm
for(int i = 1; i <= n.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= n.length; j++) {
        if(n[j]<n[i]) {
            int c = n[j];
            n[j] = n[i];
            n[i] = c;
        }
    }
}

//Printing the values of the array
    for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i ++)
        System.out.println(n[i]);       
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: 1) `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` index starts from `0` and goes to `n.length - 1`

2) `i < n.length - 1` 
3) `j = i + 1`

Comment: Also, don't reset `j` to before `i` or you'll swap elements out of order again. `for (int j = 1` should be `for (int j = i + 1;` **and** `i=0` to `i < n.length - 1` **and** `j = i + 1; j < n.length`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this just to sort it, perhaps try just using `Arrays.sort(n)`.

[Documentation for Arrays class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

If you're doing it just because you wan't to write your own sort function then there's a lot more that you need to do. Will the `Arrays.sort(n)` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The following array shall be sorted.

> int[] n = {2, 9, 56, 73, 32, 8, 23, 21, 12, 53, 9, 0, 1};

```
public int [] sort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if ( (array[i] > array[j]) && (i != j) ) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

The array can be sorted by calling sort method with array as parameter e.g.

```
int[] array = {2, 9, 56, 73, 32, 8, 23, 21, 12, 53, 9, 0, 1};
int[] sortedArray = sort(array);
```